# How to activate different Python codes on user request?

Tags: python

beginner here.

**CONTEXT**: I just started coding last month. I am a translation and interpretation student, and have kind of a thesis project. I chose to create a assistive program for translators that would make things like looking up words online easier etc. I have greatly benefitted from StackOverflow and similar sites in creating a few codes that work well -for a beginner at least.

What I need is a way to combine my small codes into one bigger program in which the user can choose which function of my project they would like to use. I have, for example, a timer that gives the user notification to take a break in given intervals and an integrated API for machine translation.

I looked online for similar problems but they did not include commands for working on user demand. What I have in my mind is a program that works like:

When you run the code, it asks you "Which tool would you like to use? Translation or timer?" and runs the appropriate command on user demand. Here are my two codes for example: First is my machine translation API and the latter is my notification timer.

```
import requests
print('Welcome to the translation tool. Below are some language codes for you to use:')
print('English -> en, Turkish -> tr, Spanish -> es, French -> fr, Russian -> ru, Chinese -> zh.')
print('***You can type "e" into the source word box to exit the program.***')

sourcelang = str(input('Which language would you like to translate FROM?: '))
targetlang = str(input('Which language would you like to translate TO?: '))

while 1==1:
    url = "https://systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com/translation/text/translate"
    word = str(input('Which word would you like to look up?: '))

    querystring = {"source":sourcelang, "target":targetlang, "input":word}

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': "8a96426f46msh7c7b8957d8b6d49p12c046jsnf7904623bf34",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)

    if word == str('e'):
        print ('Thanks for using this software. Have a good one.')
        break
```

and

```
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom
import time

userinput = input('Specify time intervals in minutes: ')

print('Timer started, will notify to take a break in specified intervals.')

while 1 == 1:

    notifString = """
    <toast>
        <visual>
            <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                <text>Time to Get Up</text>
                <text>Stretch Your Legs</text>
            </binding>
        </visual>
    </toast>
    """
    notifTime = float(userinput)
    notifManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
    notif = notifManager.create_toast_notifier()
    xmlNotif = dom.XmlDocument()
    xmlNotif.load_xml(notifString)

    def givenotification(t) :
        time.sleep(t*60)
        notif.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xmlNotif))

    givenotification(notifTime)
```

Please do let me know if my question is too vague or you need some more details. Thanks in advance.

P.S: Additional help to make my code and program look better would be much appreciated :)

Comment: If I have correctly understood your problem, you have a bunch of tools and search *something* to help users to access your tools. This is called a *main menu*. Python provides some tools to help you to build that. For a command line (no GUI) menu, you could have a look at the `cmd` module from the standard library. Or if you want something a bit more *sexy*, you could use a GUI library. You will have the basic Tkinter which is part of the standard library, or Python interfaces for more powerful libraries like PySide2 or PyQt5 for example, both targetting the well known Qt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `execfile('filename.py')` in `Python2`

or

You can use the `exec(open('filename.py').read())` in `Python3`

```
import os

choice=input("Which tool would you like to use? Translation or timer?")

if choice.lower() == "translation":
     exec(open('translation.py').read())

elif choice.lower() == "timer":
     exec(open('timer.py').read())

else:
     print("Only 2 options available(Translation/Timer")
```

Or you can simply import the another translation and timer file as a module and execute their functions in the `if else` block

Comment: I got confused with exec and execfile but thanks for explantion

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this code also launches the selected option, which works best for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a file using os module. You can use that and if else block to check user input and run the file you want to. Here is an example:

```
import os

choice=input("Which tool would you like to use? Translation or timer?")

if choice.lower() == "translation":
     os.startfile("Translation.py")#Your file path here

elif choice.lower() == "timer":
     os.startfile("Timer.py")

else:
     print("Only 2 options available(Translation/Timer")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am guessing this would also allow me to run the timer in the background while the user uses the other tools, right?

Comment: Yes, because they are separate files, you can run both of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap both the tools into their own methods, then give the user the choice at the start of the program (in `main()` with this example):

```
import requests
import winrt.windows.ui.notifications as notifications
import winrt.windows.data.xml.dom as dom
import time

def Translate():
    print('Welcome to the translation tool. Below are some language codes for you to use:')
    print('English -> en, Turkish -> tr, Spanish -> es, French -> fr, Russian -> ru, Chinese -> zh.')
    print('***You can type "e" into the source word box to exit the program.***')

    sourcelang = str(input('Which language would you like to translate FROM?: '))
    if word == str('e'):
            print ('Thanks for using this software. Have a good one.')
            break
    targetlang = str(input('Which language would you like to translate TO?: '))

    while 1==1:
        url = "https://systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com/translation/text/translate"
        word = str(input('Which word would you like to look up?: '))
        querystring = {"source":sourcelang, "target":targetlang, "input":word}
        headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-key': "8a96426f46msh7c7b8957d8b6d49p12c046jsnf7904623bf34",
            'x-rapidapi-host': "systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        print(response.text)

def givenotification(t) :
    time.sleep(t*60)
    notif.show(notifications.ToastNotification(xmlNotif))

def Timer():
    userinput = input('Specify time intervals in minutes: ')
    print('Timer started, will notify to take a break in specified intervals.')
    while 1 == 1:
        notifString = """
        <toast>
            <visual>
                <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                    <text>Time to Get Up</text>
                    <text>Stretch Your Legs</text>
                </binding>
            </visual>
        </toast>
        """
        notifTime = float(userinput)
        notifManager = notifications.ToastNotificationManager
        notif = notifManager.create_toast_notifier()
        xmlNotif = dom.XmlDocument()
        xmlNotif.load_xml(notifString)       
        givenotification(notifTime)

def main():
    choice = ''
    while choice != '3':
        choice = input('Which tool would you like to use? 1->Translate, 2->Timer, 3->Quit')
        if choice == '1':
            Translate()
        elif choice == '2':
            Timer()

main()
```

I also moved the `if word == str('e):` up so you don't have to wait for a http request just to quit the program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I added the part where you exit the program at the last second and had not even realized ^^